# UIWebView inside UITableView scroll?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have `UIWebView` inside each `UITableView` cell.

My `UIWebView` is simple, it contains only two lines, one is bold, and one is regular.

Everything is working fine, except `UIWebView` is only loading HTML string when scrolling is stopped, it isn't loading while scrolling `UITableView`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

And a UITableView is part of a UIScrollView ;)

Can't you get data as a webservice (json or xml) and add UILabel into your tableview ?

Seems to be easier ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Cell dynamically and attach external/dynamic data to the UILabels.